# How to solve 'No such file or directory: u'/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/launch/openni_node.launch'?

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use ubuntu 12.04 with fuerte.

I followed [rgbdslam](http://ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam).

When I run rgbdslam,it shows the error:

```
  sam@sam:/media/Data/code/ros/slam/rgbdslam$ roslaunch rgbdslam kinect+rgbdslam.launch 
  ... logging to /home/sam/.ros/log/07543c9e-f807-11e1-8779-20cf30a23845/roslaunch-sam-21581.log
  Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
  Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
  Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
  
  while processing /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/launch/openni_node.launch:
  Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/launch/openni_node.launch'
  sam@sam:/media/Data/code/ros/slam/rgbdslam$
```

How to solve it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43173/how-to-solve-%27no-such-file-or-directory:-u%27/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/launch/openni_node.launch%27?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-09-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I get rgbdslam to work as follows

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
rosrun rgbdslam rgbdslam
```

The topics that are necessary for rgbdslam node are published by openni.launch file. Just don't use kinect+rgbdslam. This has been working for me

---

Originally posted by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) with karma: 796 on 2012-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The openni drivers have changed in fuerte, and the kinect+rgbdslam.launch launch file is looking for the electric openni_camera launch file.  You can fix this by changing the kinect+rgbdslam.launch file as such:

change

```
<include file="$(find openni_camera)/launch/openni_node.launch"/>
```

to

```
<include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/openni.launch"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [RossK](https://answers.ros.org/users/3194/rossk/) with karma: 141 on 2012-09-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Flowers](https://answers.ros.org/users/2441/flowers/) on 2012-09-16**:
Tip: Make sure you have installed openni_launch, as it is no longer included in the openni_camera package.

**Comment by [kleinsplash](https://answers.ros.org/users/5014/kleinsplash/) on 2013-06-11**:
This really looks like the answer.. but why it is not working for me - I do not know.. had to go with @yygyt